# Wordpress - как взять отрывок поста

Tags: php, wordpress

Необходимо выводить отрывок поста. Вывожу его стандартной функцией `the_excerpt`. Проблема в том, что если отрывок у поста отсутствует, то тогда берутся первые несколько слов из полного описания. Мне нужно сделать, чтобы если отрывок отсутствует, то чтобы ничего не выводилось (или пустая строка). Можно ли добавить какой либо фильтр в functions, чтобы реализовать это?
Пробовал в function.php добавлять такой код:

```
function new_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 0;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');
```

Тогда если отрывок поста есть, то он выводится, но если его нет, то выводится

> [...]

Мне бы эту строку "[...]" убрать.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Добавил в functions.php код:

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```